# ftp process is not working properly

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ftp

I have a ssis package that does the following

1. copies a file from an ftp to a folder. overwrite if it exists
2. copy data to sql db
3. delete file from ftp

i have send email task if the ftp fails.

Scheduled this ssis in jobs. 
I created a 2MB test file and ran the job. Works perfect!

now tried with a 500 MB file in the ftp. Works pefect when i run it from the IDE.

When i execute the job

1. ftp file is NOT copied
2. data is copied from existing file

no errors returned. package executed successfully. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was

it was a directory permission issue. Sql server doesnot throw any error message when the ftp task does not copy.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a silent timeout or such.

Have you considered zipping/unzipping to reduce the actual FTP duration and size?